# How to setup NLog with Sustainsys.Saml2

Tags: c#, nlog, sustainsys-saml2

I have an ASP.Net Web Forms app where I just integrated [Sustainsys.Saml2](https://saml2.sustainsys.com/en/stable/getting-started.html) library.

I've never used any sort of logging mechanism and I'm trying to figure out how to add or create an `ILoggerAdapter` for the library stated on their [troubleshooting](https://saml2.sustainsys.com/en/stable/troubleshooting.html) page.

I've decided to use NLog (please feel free to recommend a different one) and either I'm not understanding this well, or am not using the right keyword to search for what I need/want, or their isn't a lot of documentation on it.

Currently, I'm using the `HttpModule` version of `Sustainsys.Saml2`. Any other information available upon request.

Any help would be great.

Currently, I'm configuring the `Sustainsys.Saml2` library through both web.config and the global.asax files. Here's the class my global.asax calls:

```
public class Saml2Config {
    private static bool _alreadyInitialized;
    private static readonly object Lock = new object();

    public static void Initialize() {
        if (_alreadyInitialized) {
            return;
        }

        lock (Lock) {
            if (_alreadyInitialized) {
                return;
            }

            var domain = PageHelper.GetDomainURL(true);

            Sustainsys.Saml2.Configuration.Options.FromConfiguration.SPOptions.EntityId.Id = $"{domain}/federation/Saml2";
            Sustainsys.Saml2.Configuration.Options.FromConfiguration.SPOptions.ModulePath = "/federation/Saml2";
            Sustainsys.Saml2.Configuration.Options.FromConfiguration.SPOptions.ReturnUrl = new Uri($"{domain}/mybarry");
            Sustainsys.Saml2.Configuration.Options.FromConfiguration.SPOptions.PublicOrigin = new Uri($"{domain}");

            Sustainsys.Saml2.Configuration.Options.FromConfiguration.SPOptions.Logger = new NullLoggerAdapter();

            _alreadyInitialized = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the type of Sustainsys.Saml2.Configuration.Options.FromConfiguration.SPOptions.Logger? Are there any API docs of it?

Comment: @Julian it's an `ILoggerAdapter`. I don't see any docs about it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[The interface](https://github.com/Sustainsys/Saml2/blob/ad39f77c7c55279231d12d601c115f01a76f8ff4/Sustainsys.Saml2/ILoggerAdapter.cs) is pretty straightforward

```cs
public interface ILoggerAdapter
{
    void WriteInformation(string message);

    void WriteError(string message, Exception ex);

    void WriteVerbose(string message);
}
```

I would implement it as follows:

```cs
public class NLogAdapter : ILoggerAdapter
{
    private static Logger Logger = LogManager.GetLogger("Saml2");

    public void WriteInformation(string message)
    {
        Logger.Info(message);
    }

    public void WriteError(string message, Exception ex)
    {
        Logger.Error(ex, message);
    }

    public void WriteVerbose(string message)
    {
        Logger.Debug(message);
    }
}
```

And  finally set it:

```cs
Sustainsys.Saml2.Configuration.Options.FromConfiguration.SPOptions.Logger = new NLogAdapter();
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked too. Though I worked off of the previous answer, because you gave a complete working example, I'll mark it as the answer so it's easier for others to follow.

Answer (score 1):

The `ILoggerAdapter` contains methods for different loglevels. Make an adapter class that implements `ILoggerAdapter` and writes to NLog. Then set `SPOptions.Logger` to an instance of your adapter class.

If you want an example, you can check out the adapter for Asp.Net Core that logs to the Asp.Net Core logging system and is the default for the `Sustainsys.Saml2.AspNetCore2` package: https://github.com/Sustainsys/Saml2/blob/master/Sustainsys.Saml2.AspNetCore2/AspNetCoreLoggerAdapter.cs

For the `Sustainsys.Saml2.HttpModule` library the default is the `NullLoggerAdapter` which simply discards any logs. Only reason to use it is to not have to nullcheck the Logger property everywhere it is used (that code was written before the `?.` syntax was introduced.)

Comment: Thank you! I'll try it out (need to see why it won't trigger a logout to the IDP).

Comment: The logic for triggering a federated logout is quite complex. There is a log message written with all the conditions so the logger definitely helps.
https://github.com/Sustainsys/Saml2/blob/ad39f77c7c55279231d12d601c115f01a76f8ff4/Sustainsys.Saml2/WebSSO/LogOutCommand.cs#L175

Comment: Thank you, it worked. All the values are blank in the log for the requirements, so I got some figuring out to do. Though I followed your instructions, I'll give the next answer credit since it'll be easier for others to see. Wish I could mark both.

Comment: Hi, I posted a followup question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61663562/why-metadata-failed-to-load-from-adfs-using-sustainsys-saml2